# Randomize a set of spoken phrases in a script to only speak one of them at a time

Tags: random, vbscript, voice, cd

I'm looking to randomize a set of spoken phrases listed below so only one of them speaks each time the CD drive is ejected.

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
wscript.sleep 600000
do
if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Randomize
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "My life for Ire"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "I Love You"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "please, help me"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "Feed me"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "i am so alone"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "to arms my brothers"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "hey, listen."
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "death to all"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "dum dee dee dum dee dum"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "the hunger is overwhelming"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "over here"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "dont ever leave me"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "duck duck goose"
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "Autobots, roll out"
Next
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next
End If
Randomize
wscript.sleep Int(120000*Rnd)
loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your message strings in an array. Then you can chose a random array index and thus get a different message every time.

Example Code (I left out some of your messages to avoid scrolling bars or line splitting but it works with any number of messages):

```
messages = Array("My life for Ire", "I Love You", "please, help me")

set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

Randomize
msgNr = Int(((Ubound(messages)+1)*Rnd))
oVoice.Speak messages(msgNr )
```